# Can't match a Slim Framework route when using GET parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, xampp, slim

I have the following route defined, I'm using Slim Framework 2:

```
$app->map('/mail', function () use ($app) {
    $mails = array('Hola como estas?', 'Valar Margulis', 'Hola Ariel, este mensaje se autodestruira') ;
    $respuesta = array(
        'mails' => $mails
    ) ;

    $respuestaJson = json_encode($respuesta) ;

    die($respuestaJson) ;
})->via('GET', 'POST');


$app->run();
```

When I try the route http://slim/mail it works

But then when I try to pass any GET parameter http://slim/mail?inbox=whatever

I get a 404 error, what am I doing wrong?

Edit:

This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It should work. Can you post your .htaccess?

Comment: I added my .htaccess to the question, I forgot to check that

Comment: try to replace `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]` with `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`. Tell me if it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That 404 error was apache, not Slim. Simply replace with

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```